# How to simply (AB')' or (ABC')'?

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

Stuck on one aspect of a question for Computer Architecture I: Digital Design, and am not sure how to simplify (ABC')' or even (AB').

Not sure if any axiom or theorem can be applied, or if (ABC')' [or (AB')'] is the most simplified form. Can someone confirm?

Comment: Hello and welcome on StackOverflow!!! In order to get your a better answer, and your answer don't get deleted later on, you would have to read and follow some basic rules and conventions that will help everyone to communicate and help better. Please go to https://stackoverflow.com/help and read about the topic "What topics can I ask about here?", and "What types of questions should I avoid asking?".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question about mathematical logic, not computer programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can splat `(ABC')'` into `A' + B' + C`; similarly, `(AB')'` is `A' + B` (according to De Morgan's laws). These are [disjunctive normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form).

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon what Amadan said:

```
(AB')' + (ABC')'
A' + B + A' + B' + C          DeMorgan applie twice
A' + A' + B + B'+ C           commutativity of disjunction
A' + B + B' + C               x + x = x
A' + 1 + C                    x + x' = 1
1 + C                         x + 1 = 1
1                             1 + x = 1
```

Upon reflection this must be the case since B must be either true or false, and each of these values makes one or the other of the original terms true.